# Is it at all possible to design a macro that expands to a length?

Tags: macros, programming, lengths

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get width of a given text as length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length)

In an attempt to [Compute the x distance between two nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63831/8057), the question arose whether it is at all possible to devise [A macro that expands to the length of its argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13400/8057), or to any length. (The actual value or the way of obtaining it is irrelevant here.) Would it be necessary to generate a decimal representation of the length and parse it? How and why does the `\widthof` macro referred to in the linked question work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\footextwidth}[1]{%
  % Should expand to the natural width of the argument
  1cm
}

\begin{document}
    A test for the macro.

    A \parbox{\footextwidth{test}}{~} for the macro.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use `\newcommand{\footextwidth}[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\the\wd0}`

Comment: The direct answer to the question is **no** - you can't have a macro which expands to the length of some text, because you absolutely need to assign a box inbetween. The nearest you can get is the `\setlength` approach used below. While doing an assignment anyway, you can as well assign a box inbetween, which is what `\widthof` does.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Then perhaps *expands* is the wrong word for this. I want to use an invocation of this macro *in place of* an actual length. Have to look at what Marco provided.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Care to write this as an answer?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Did you try that? I don't think it works.

Comment: @user946850 The answer is still more or less **no**. The `\setlength` trick is more or less the only solution.

Comment: \widthof (or the \wd primitive) are for reporting the length of a _box_ but there are no boxes between Tikz nodes to measure. As far as I understand it (having not used the system) Tikz nodes (like latex picture mode) are already positioned at specific coordinates, so you just need to ask tikz what those cordinates are and then use pythagoras.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In fact, as seen in the answers to the linked question, it is possible to *compute* the distance between two nodes, even as a dimension. What I am looking for is how to write a macro that *evaluates to* this dimension.

Comment: Another direct answer to your question: Your original version of `\footextwidth` in the MWE is a macro which expands to a length. You really must say precisely what you are asking *in this question*.

Comment: @user946850 since (in a TeX context) neither _compute_ nor _evaluate_ are defined terms you will need to explain what you mean by the difference between compute and evaluate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\usepackage{calc}` in your preamble, you could use `\parbox{\widthof{test}}`.  The `\wdithof{<text>}` returns the width of the given `<text>`.

A better alternative for this is `hphantom{test}` which will take up as much horizontal space as required by `test`.  There is a corresponding `vphantom{}` for vertical space, and `\phantom{}`.

If you want to store the width for latter use you can use:

```
 \newlength{\MyLength}
 \settowidth{\MyLength}{<text>}
```

and then the value of `\MyLength` can be used whereever a lenght is required.
Int he last example below, the space is prodced by `\hspace{\MyLength}`.

[image]

### Notes:

- As Higgs Boson commented, `\textwidth` is already defined so a different name should be used.
- There are cases where one can not use `\widthof{}` directly: [How to use \widthof as parameter to \kern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54015/how-to-use-widthof-as-parameter-to-kern).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\MyFixedWidth}{1cm}


\newlength{\MyLength}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
    A test for the macro.                           & no spacing\\
    A \parbox{\MyFixedWidth}{~} for the macro. & use length \verb|\MyFixedWidth| = \MyFixedWidth\\
    A \parbox{\widthof{test}}{~} for the macro.     & use \verb|\widthof{test}|\\
    A \hphantom{test} for the macro.                & use \verb|\hphantom{test}|\\
    \settowidth{\MyLength}{test}%                   
    A \hspace{\MyLength} for the macro.             & use \verb|\hspace{\MyLength}|\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right. I'm more interested in how you would code such a beast.

Comment: @user946850: Not sure I understand what you want to code.

Comment: I mean, just like `\widthof` -- a macro that "prints" the natural length of the argument so that it can be "processed" by a command that requires a dimension. I understand that `\widthof` is a command which is defined only in, e.g., `\parbox` by the `calc` package, and that it just doesn't seem to be possible to implement a generic `\widthof` which always can be used directly (that's what I was interested in).

Comment: Still not understanding. You want to implement `\widthof`, then just copy the definition of `\widthof`?  Perhaps an actual example usage is required to fully understand what you desire.

Comment: No. I want to use `\widthof{}` where a dimension is required. Other questions and answers seem to indicate that this won't work and that it's impossible to implement such a macro.