# Changing color within word in script font

Tags: fonts, color

I am writing some text for our school and it needs to be in some German-Script-Font (Schulausgangsschrift) which I do using the package "Schulschriften".

Some letters of the words need to be colored, some don't.
But if I change the color using `\color` or `\textcolor` the script letters are not properly connected anymore.

Do you have any advice?

Here are my results:

[image: Example]

And here is my code to get this:

```
\documentclass[28pt,a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage{wesa}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

This Text ist in one color, so the last o is correctly connected to the t:\\
\wesa Boot

\normalfont
Using color: o and t are not properly connected:\\
\wesa 
B\color{red}oo\color{black}t

\normalfont
Same with textcolor:\\
\wesa
B\textcolor{red}{oo}\textcolor{black}t

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike already pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477143/losing-ligatures-when-switching-font-series-or-color-in-the-middle-of-a-word), using `luacolor` will fix the issue (you have to use LuaLaTeX to compile):

```
\documentclass[28pt,a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage{wesa}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}

This Text ist in one color, so the last o is correctly connected to the t:\\
\wesa Boot

\normalfont
Using color: o and t are not properly connected:\\
\wesa 
B\color{red}oo\color{black}t

\normalfont
Same with textcolor:\\
\wesa
B\textcolor{red}{oo}\textcolor{black}t

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's just what I needed.